# What 486 motherboard is this, with American Megatrends BIOS identifying is DPAQ-6156-043090-KF?

Tags: intel, identify-this-computer, x86

I've got an early 486 motherboard that doesn't seem to have a manufacturer name or FCC number on it and I'm having trouble identifying it.

I've placed some photos of the motherboard in this [Imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN5Wn.jpg).

The BIOS ID on the boot screen is:

```
(C) American Megatrends Inc.,

     DPAQ-6156-043090-KF
```

Comment: As far as I know there were a lot of "no-name" 486 motherboards... I've heard about a company in the "486 era" manufacturing graphics cards existing only for about a month.

Comment: Generic board in a genericcase - not much chance to get any identification.

Comment: The Zymos/Appian POACH (PC-on-a-chip) chipset was developed for PC-AT (286) compatibles, introduced in 1987. The fact that it's used on a 486 board in 1992 indicates this is a budget, low-end machine.

Comment: I suspect that the logo of a flag with "HL" on it, on the reverse of the board, would indicate the manufacturer. The trouble is in finding any information on Taiwanese motherboard manufacturers of the early 1990s.

Comment: Does it boot? Does it print a BIOS ID?

Comment: [This page on identifying by BIOS ID](https://www.wimsbios.com/aminumbers.jsp) _might_ help, especially if you _can_ get the BIOS ID. If the "HL" _is_ the manufacturer's logo, it's _possible_ it could be "**High Large Corporation**" (BIOS ID 1957)... but they don't seem to show up on the web (other than in BIOS lists).

Comment: @StephenKitt the [earliest wayback machine entry for Genoa](https://web.archive.org/web/19961105055846/http://www.genoasys.com/product.html) only shows Pentium motherboards, but [this page](http://www.elhvb.com/webhq/models/486vlb3/te486vl.txt.html) seems to suggest they did in fact make 486 motherboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.idhw.com/textual/guide/inst_mobo_ami.html offers the following breakdown of the BIOS ID:

- D: BIOS w/ diagnostics
- PAQ: Compaq compatible 386 boards
- 6156: this Manufacturer code is [not listed](http://www.idhw.com/textual/guide/inst_mobo_ami_manu.html), but **Genoa** is 6165 and **American Predator Corp.** is 6155, so possibly an alternative code for one of those. Wim's BIOS [lists](https://www.wimsbios.com/aminumbers.jsp) 6156 as **Genoa**.
- 043090: MMDDYY BIOS release date
- KF: AMI keyboard BIOS rev. level

[**GENOA SYSTEMS CORPORATION 486 BABY AT**](https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/motherboards/G/GENOA-SYSTEMS-CORPORATION-486-486-BABY-AT.html) seems to be somewhat similar to your photos, although chipset is listed as UMC, so possibly you have an earlier version. The **FAB** marking on the back also suggests that this could be a development or test version of the board.

Comment: Man with such a weird bord fixing it won't be easy, I was replacing the CMOS battery and pulled a pad :(

Comment: Just throwing this out there, another possibility that exactly matches the photograph (memory, jumpers, connectors, BIOS Even/Odd position, CPU socket, co-processor socket, cache, and tag) with the exception that SW2 is labeled SW1 is the https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/motherboards/K/KOUWELL-ELECTRONIC-CORPORATION-486-486-33EZ.html

Comment: @Geo... great find! you should post it as an answer

Comment: @Igor, I've updated my answer with the new suggested motherboard.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm editing my answer (again).*

Originally I thought this board might be a variation of:

[BEC COMPUTER ENTERPRISE 80486AT (Ver. 1.0)](https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/motherboards/B/BEC-COMPUTER-ENTERPRISE-486-80486AT-Ver-1-0.html)

Everything except the position of the BIOS and the TAG seemed to match, but that could have been errors in the diagram.

However, I am now thinking this is a better match:

**[KOUWELL ELECTRONIC CORPORATION 486-33EZ](https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/motherboards/K/KOUWELL-ELECTRONIC-CORPORATION-486-486-33EZ.html)**

As near as I can tell, everything on this diagram matches the pictures from the OP, with two exceptions.  First, there is a bank of dip switches labeled SW1 on the diagram but this switch is labeled SW2 and shaped differently in the OP's picture. Second, there is a (I think) battery displayed in the corner of the board on the diagram, but no such battery exists in the OP's picture (but the silkscreen in the OP's picture looks like there was space/connections for the battery) (if it is a battery).

I'm not ignoring the great detective work by Igor, but the Genoa board in his answer doesn't seem to match the physical layout of the OP's picture. However the BEC board is close, and the KOUWELL board is *really* close.

Comment: The "TAG" sockets are also slightly misplaced. Also https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/motherboards/m486_t.html lists two BEC Ver 1.0 motherboards at different links which seems odd.

Comment: That Kouwell board has a Dallas RTC in the corner that isn't there on the board in the photos. Yet another similar board, from Freetech, https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/motherboards/F/FREE-COMPUTER-TECHNOLOGY-INC-486-80486EISA-VERSION.html  
 who also used 0x-xxxxx-xx model numbers, has SW1 where the one pictured in the question has SW1 and SW2. This kind of sleuthing is okay for coming up with an incomplete list of possible manufacturer guesses, but without a 100% match it's not anything more than that. There are _so_ many similar board layouts.

Comment: Ah, I thought that RTC was a battery.  But either way, it looks to me like it was _removed_ from the OP's board. -  The Freetech is similar, but has greater variation than the Kouwell...  I agree it's not an exact science.

Comment: The Freetech board is called EISA. The board in the photo does not have EISA slots. If the pictures at TULARC are correct and I read them correctly, the Kouwell board also has all but two slots as EISA slots.